# Leaving only one space between words within a paragraph

Tags: whitespace

I have read https://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/DeletingWhitespace but couldn't find a way to select a paragraph and remove extra white spaces. For instance:

> asd asdasd asdasd asdasdasd  asdasda  asdasdasdasd asdasdasdasdasdasd
> asdasd asdasd asdasdasd  asdasda  asdasdasdasd asdasdasdasdasdasd
> asdasd asdasd asdasdasd  asdasda  asdasdasdasd asdasdasdasdasdasd
> asdasd asdasd asdasdasd  asdasda  asdasdasdasd asdasdasdasdasdasd
> asdasd asdasd asdasdasd  asdasda  asdasdasdasd asdasdasdasdasd

I'd like to be able to select this chunk and apply a function to leave just one white space between words.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`M-x fill-paragraph` will reformat the selected paragraph such that there is only a single space between each word.

It will also 'fill' the paragraph, which means inserting line-breaks in order to keep each line shorter than `fill-column` characters long. If you don't want your lines broken like this, you could set the variable `fill-column` to a large value (i.e., 10000).

Comment: Yeah, this could work. I have a different function to remove newlines that I can apply afterwards, since I don't want it to become a formatted paragraph. Thanks!